# Display two property combination in select option

Tags: angularjs

Following is my select box

```
<select ng-model="colour" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in colors" ng-init="colour=2">
    <option value="">--Select Colour--</option>
</select>
```

and following is code in controller

```
$scope.colors = [
    {id: 1, name: 'black', shade: 'dark'},
    {id: 2, name: 'white', shade: 'light'},
    {id: 3, name: 'red', shade: 'dark'},
    {id: 4, name: 'blue', shade: 'dark'},
    {id: 5, name: 'yellow', shade: 'light'}
];
```

In this select only name of the colour is displayed and my requirement is to show both name and shade in the option text. I have tried but no luck and did not found any useful post to do this.

Anybody have some idea to display both name and shade in the select option text (ed., `black dark`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append the shade to the name in the expression:

```
ng-options="c.id as (c.name + ' ' + c.shade) for c in colors"
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/4Pyu5/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Hi have to update your `ng-options` expression
For example:

```
c.id as c.name + ' ' + c.shade for c in colors
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one more way to do this

```
<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller="MyController">
    <select ng-model="colour">
        <option value="">--Select Client--</option>
        <option ng-value="c.id" ng-selected="c.id==11"
            ng-repeat="c in colors">{{c.name + ' ' + c.shade}}</option>
    </select>

    <p>You have selected colour: {{colour}}</p>
</div>
```

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkbharti/3Js2m/)</kbd>